# Get Lat and Long, Android

Tags: android, android-mapview, latitude-longitude

I need lat and lng of a point on a google map. It has to look like that

8.53171539306641 for example

but when I go to maps.google.com I get just

8.532493

There is a possibility to receive lat and lng that have such a length 8.53171539306641 but I do not remember how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you would have looked into this: Try receiving the value in a double precision data type.

If this doesn't solve it, could you please paste some code for us to get a good sense of what exactly you are trying to achieve.